# Lusin´s Theorem continuity part

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

I need to prove: $f:R \rightarrow R$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if $\forall \epsilon \exists E=E(\epsilon)$ open with $ \lambda (E) < \epsilon$ such that $f |_{R-E}:R-E \rightarrow R  $ is continuos.

I already proved that $f$ is lebesgue measurable if the open set exists, my problem is with the other direction, proving that $f |_{R-E}$ is continuous. Here is what I have up to now:

Let $\epsilon > 0$, let $ (u_i)_i^{\infty}$ be a countable base for $R$'s topology. Since $f^{-1}(u_i) \in A_R^*$ (sigma algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets) $\forall i \in N$ then $\exists F_i$ closed and $G_i$ open such that $ F_i \subset f^{-1}(u_i) \subset G_i $ with $\lambda (G_i - F_i) < \epsilon /2^i$. Then, let $E= \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}G_i - F_i  $ which is open, and $ \lambda (E) < \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda (G_i - F_i) < \epsilon$

Now I need to prove $f |_{R-E}:R-E \rightarrow R  $ is continuos. My professor suggestion is to prove $f^{-1} _{R-E}(u_i) = O \cap (R-E)$ where $O$ is a general open set (therefore a union of $u_i$´s), so I tried to prove $f^{-1} _{R-E}(u_i) = G_i\cap (R-E)$, and I was able to prove $\subseteq$ but I don´t knwo how to prove $\supseteq$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $K = R - E$ and $g = f \mid_{K}$.

You already know that $K$ is closed and $E = \cup (G_j \setminus F_j)$ (I changed the index variable to lessen confusion), so apply DeMorgan's Law:
$$K = R - E = \bigg( \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} G_j \setminus F_j \bigg)^c = \bigg( \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} G_j \cap F_j^c \bigg)^c = \bigcap\limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} (G_j^c \sqcup F_j) $$

Then revisiting your countable base, where $R = \{ u_i \}$:

\begin{align}
g^{pre}(u_i) &= f^{pre}(u_i) \cap K\\
&\subset G_i \cap K \\
&= G_i \cap \bigg(\bigcap\limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} (G_j^c \sqcup F_j) \bigg) \\
&\subset G_i \cap (G_i^c \sqcup F_i)\\
&= G_i \cap F_i \\
&= F_i \subset g^{pre}(u_i)
\end{align}

Then $g^{pre} (u_i) = G_i \cap K$ is open in $K$. In your notation, this is equivalent to proving that $f^{-1}_{R - E} (u_i) = O \cap (R - E)$, where $O$ is some open set.